# Next js app throwing 404 error when deployed to vercel, even though it works fine on local

Tags: next.js, deployment, http-status-code-404, vercel, i18next

this is my project directoy, i have deployed my code to vercel, it works fine on local but dynamic pages shows 404 errors on  vercel.

[image]

i added trailingSlash: true in next config but it still didnt work

Comment: Are you sure that the database has data and is connected correctly?